What is the difference between VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH , VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG , VISIBILITY_BOTH in magento 2
I am new bee to magento, I just confused with the product visbility
VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
VISIBILITY_BOTH
How the product will display on the frontend for the above option selected.
For example, I set VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG for a particular product, Then at frontend, If i am at some custom cms page, I enter the product sku on global search whether the product should be visible at the same page or not?

These are the product search option and working in following way
VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH: This option makes the product visible only in search results. It means that customers can find the product through the search function but it won't appear in the catalog or category listings.
VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG: This option makes the product visible only in catalog pages. It means that customers can see the product when browsing through categories or other catalog pages, but it won't show up in search results.
VISIBILITY_BOTH: This option makes the product visible both in the catalog and in search results. This is the most common setting for products that you want to be easily discoverable by customers.
